# Remove an XML parent node keeping child nodes

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

If I have (for example) an XML file with the following structure:

```xml
<Parent1>
      <listChild>
           <child>
               <listchild2>
                    <child2>
                    <child2>
                    <child2>
               </listchild2>
           </child>
           <child>
                <listchild2>
                     <child2>
                     <child2>
                     <child2>
                </listchild2>
           </child>
      </listchild>
</parent1>
```

I want to remove `listChild` and `listChild2`, with the expected output:

```xml
 <Parent>
       <child>
          <child>
          <child>
          <child>
       </child>
       <child>
          <child>
          <child>
          <child>
       </child>
</parent>
```

I tried `System.Xml.Linq`, like this:

```
public void removeParentNode(String filename)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

    //remove parent1 
    var child= xdoc.Descendants("child");                       
    XElement dcuManager = new XElement("parent1 ");
    parent1 .Add(child);

    XDocument xdoc1 = new XDocument(dcuManager);
}
```

But the code removes only the outer list.

Is there a way to remove the `<listchild>` and `</listchild>` tags only, keeping all its child nodes?

------------------------update-------------------------------------

above xml code is very simple example
my xml code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DcuManager xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <listDcu>
    <Dcu id="dcu1 id" mode="dcu1 mode" port="dcu1 port">
      <modemMgr>
        <listModem>
          <Modem id="Modem1 id" port="modem 1 port" communicationStatus="modem 1 mode">
            <meterManager>
              <listMeter>
                <Meter id="Meter 1 id" port="Meter 1 port" mac="Meter 1 mode" />
              </listMeter>
            </meterManager>
          </Modem>
          <Modem id="Modem2 id" port="modem 2 port" communicationStatus="modem 2 mode">
            <meterManager>
              <listMeter>
                <Meter id="Meter 2 id" port="Meter 2 port" mac="Meter 2 mode" />
              </listMeter>
            </meterManager>
          </Modem>
        </listModem>
      </modemMgr>
    </Dcu>
    <Dcu id="dcu2 id" mode="dcu2 mode" port="dcu2 port">
      <modemMgr>
        <listModem>
          <Modem id="Modem3 id" port="modem 3 port" communicationStatus="modem 3 mode">
            <meterManager>
              <listMeter>
                <Meter id="Meter 3 id" port="Meter 3 port" mac="Meter 3 mode" />
              </listMeter>
            </meterManager>
          </Modem>
          <Modem id="Modem4 id" port="modem 4 port" communicationStatus="modem 4 mode">
            <meterManager>
              <listMeter>
                <Meter id="Meter 4 id" port="Meter 4 port" mac="Meter 4 mode" />
              </listMeter>
            </meterManager>
          </Modem>
        </listModem>
      </modemMgr>
    </Dcu>
    <Dcu id="dcu3 id" mode="dcu3 mode" port="dcu3 port">
      <modemMgr>
        <listModem>
          <Modem id="Modem5 id" port="modem 5 port" communicationStatus="modem 5 mode">
            <meterManager>
              <listMeter>
                <Meter id="Meter 5 id" port="Meter 5 port" mac="Meter 5 mode" />
              </listMeter>
            </meterManager>
          </Modem>
          <Modem id="Modem6 id" port="modem 6 port" communicationStatus="modem 6 mode">
            <meterManager>
              <listMeter>
                <Meter id="Meter 6 id" port="Meter 6 port" mac="Meter 6 mode" />
              </listMeter>
            </meterManager>
          </Modem>
        </listModem>
      </modemMgr>
    </Dcu>
  </listDcu>
</DcuManager>
```

this code is convert c# class to xml.
i want remove dcuMgr, modemMgr, meterMgr keeping child nodes.
how do i?

Comment: If you remove `listchild` instead your code should work fine.. Not really sure what problem you have updating your code.

Comment: Conceptually, I expect you will need to copy the content of a node, then delete the node itself, then paste into the parent node's content.  Can you make a function to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Your specification is not very clear. XML itself does not have the concept of a "list". Any element can contain any number of child elements, and XML doesn't care what the name of the elements are. Using the word "list" in an element doesn't actually make it a list.

In addition, in your example XML you show two different kinds of "child" nodes, the outer being named `child` and the inner being named `child2`. But in your desired output, you only have the name `child`. The `child2` nodes appear to have been replaced by `child` nodes.

Unfortunately, the XML you show isn't even valid XML. So it's pretty obvious you have not provided us with *real* XML examples, making it even more difficult to understand what you're trying to do.

So, with all that in mind, I'll point out that the basic approach you want, given that you want to apply the same algorithm to a series of nested objects, is one based on recursion. I.e. you want to recursively select the nodes you'll be keeping, and apply the same removal logic to them.

Here is a [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e. similar to what should have been included in the question in the first place) that illustrates this basic idea:

```
class Program
{
    const string _kxmlInput =
        @"<parent1>
      <listchild>
           <child>
               <listchild2>
                    <child/>
                    <child/>
                    <child/>
               </listchild2>
           </child>
           <child>
                <listchild2>
                     <child/>
                     <child/>
                     <child/>
                </listchild2>
           </child>
      </listchild>
</parent1>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(removeParentNode(_kxmlInput));
    }

    static string removeParentNode(string xml)
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

        //remove parent1 
        XDocument xdoc1 = new XDocument(KeepDescendants(xdoc.Root, "child"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };

        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
            xdoc1.WriteTo(xmlWriter);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static XElement KeepDescendants(XElement node, string descendantName)
    {
        var child = node.Descendants(descendantName).Select(c => KeepDescendants(c, descendantName));

        if (!child.Any())
        {
            return node;
        }

        XElement newParent = new XElement(node.Name);

        newParent.Add(child);

        return newParent;
    }
}
```

If you have some other kind of behavior in mind, you should be able to adapt the basic technique shown above to accomplish whatever it is you actually want to do.

Comment: Thank you for attention my question. i can speak little English. please understand.

Comment: Your edit didn't really clarify much. The XML isn't well-formed, and you say you want to remove the `DcuManager` node but based on your previous example that's the root node, so we're left not understanding how you expect to remove the root node. It's also not clear what distinguishes a node you want to remove/flatten from a node you want to keep. You even have a node in your new XML example with "list" in the name, but you seem to _not_ want to remove that node. I really think the above should get you most of the way, but if you still need help you need to improve the question a lot.